# Rotation: What is $\tau_r(x)=x+r (\text{mod}1)$?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\Omega=[0,1), \mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ and $\mathbb{P}=\lambda$ Lebesgue measure. Consider $r\in (0,1)$. Define
> >     $$
> > \tau_r(x):=x+r (\text{mod} 1).
> > $$

I have some questions to this:

(1) What is meant with $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, is it
$$
\left\{B\cap [0,1): B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}?
$$

(2) Is it $\lambda:=\lambda_{|\mathcal{B}(\Omega)}$?

(3) Why is it called *rotation*?

Answer (score 1):

1) ``$\mod 1$'' is the "fractional part" map from $\mathbb R$ to $\Omega$: $x \mod 1 = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\le x$.

2)  Yes

3) You're using the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$.  You could call that the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ to $\Omega$.

4) If you bend $[0,1]$ into a circle by identifying $1$ with $0$, this is rotation on that circle.

Comment: Do not see point (4), sorry. Let f.e. $r=\frac{1}{2}$, then f.e. $0\mapsto\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\mapsto 0, \frac{3}{4}\mapsto\frac{1}{4}$. In which way is this a rotation?...

Comment: Identify $[0,1)$ with a circle $\mathbb T$ using the map $x \mapsto \exp(2\pi i x)$.  Your map is a rotation of the circle.  For $r=1/2$ it is a rotation through $180^\circ$.